# How do I check if a div contains another div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to show alert if my parent div has a child div using JavaScript only No jQuery.

I have tried using the `contains()` function to check my div and send alert but it's not working.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var parentDiv = document.getElementById("commentBox");
  var childDiv = document.getElementById("comment1");
  if (parentDiv.contains(childDiv)) {
    alert("yes");
  } else
  {
    alert("no");
  }
</script>
<div class="row leftpad collapse" id="commentBox">
  <div id="comment1">
    <div class="col-md-3 dir-rat-left"> <i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <h6>James </h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 dir-rat-right">
      <p class="removemarg">always available, always helpfull that goes the same for his team that work with him - definatley our first phone call.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There should be an alert box with message `yes` in it but it's not visible. I have also tried checking JavaScript using the `alert()` method only without any code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `querySelector` . If the child is not present it will give a null value

```js
var hasChildDiv = document.getElementById("commentBox").querySelector("#comment1");
if (hasChildDiv !== null) {
  alert('yes')
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
<div class="row leftpad collapse" id="commentBox">
  <div id="comment1">
    <div class="col-md-3 dir-rat-left"> <i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <h6>James </h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 dir-rat-right">
      <p class="removemarg">always available, always helpfull that goes the same for his team that work with him - definatley our first phone call.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Your code is running before the DOM is fully loaded. Move your script at the bottom of the page:

```html
<div class="row leftpad collapse" id="commentBox" >
    <div id="comment1">
      <div class="col-md-3 dir-rat-left"> <i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <h6>James </h6>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9 dir-rat-right">
        <p class="removemarg">always available, always helpfull that goes the same for his team that work with him - definatley our first phone call.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
<script type="text/javascript">
  var parentDiv = document.getElementById("commentBox");
  var childDiv = document.getElementById("comment1");
  if (parentDiv.contains(childDiv)) {
    alert("yes");
  }
  else{
    alert("no");
  }

</script>
```

**OR:** Wrap the code with [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) which will ensure that code placed inside will be executed only after the DOM is fully loaded:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var parentDiv = document.getElementById("commentBox");
    var childDiv = document.getElementById("comment1");
    if (parentDiv.contains(childDiv)) {
      alert("yes");
    }
    else{
      alert("no");
    }
  });

</script>

<div class="row leftpad collapse" id="commentBox" >
    <div id="comment1">
      <div class="col-md-3 dir-rat-left"> <i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <h6>James </h6>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9 dir-rat-right">
        <p class="removemarg">always available, always helpfull that goes the same for his team that work with him - definatley our first phone call.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do do if i want to add this script in another file and then add in header??

Comment: @Franco, try the second solution and add the link of that file in the current page.

Answer (score 1):

```
let table = document.getElementById("niceTable");
let tds = table.getElementsByTagName("td");

for (let i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
    tds[i].onclick = function () {
        checkInputElement(tds[i]);
    };
}

function checkInputElement(element) {
    let input = element.querySelector("input");
    console.log(element.contains(input));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the whole DOM is loaded before you execute javascript code.
You can do this by adding the event listener `DOMContentLoaded` to your code or placing your scripts at the end of the file

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
        var parentDiv = document.getElementById("commentBox");
        var childDiv = document.getElementById("comment1");

        if (parentDiv && parentDiv.contains(childDiv)) {
            alert("yes");
        }
        else {
            alert("no");
        }
    }, false);
</script>


<div class="row leftpad collapse" id="commentBox" >
    <div id="comment1">
        <div class="col-md-3 dir-rat-left"> <i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <h6>James </h6>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 dir-rat-right">    
            <p class="removemarg">always available, always helpfull that goes the same for his team that work with him - definatley our first phone call.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You won't get an alert because `parentDiv` will not exist yet and the value will be `null`. This results that it does not contain the `contains()` function and it will throw an error. To be safe you can add a null check inside the if statement.

Comment: Are you sure `(function(){ }())` is the exact *thing* to use to attach handler to DOM ready?

Answer (score -1):

How about using `window.onload` function?

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var parentDiv = document.getElementById("commentBox");
        var childDiv = document.getElementById("comment1");
        if (parentDiv.contains(childDiv)) {
            alert("yes");
        } else {
            alert("no");
        }
    }
</script>
```

**[This will execute the function until dom loads completely](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)**

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var parentDiv = document.getElementById("commentBox");
        var childDiv = document.getElementById("comment1");
        if (parentDiv.contains(childDiv)) {
            alert("yes");
        } else {
            alert("no");
        }
    }
</script>
<div class="row leftpad collapse" id="commentBox">
    <div id="comment1">
        <div class="col-md-3 dir-rat-left"> <i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <h6>James </h6>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 dir-rat-right">
            <p class="removemarg">always available, always helpfull that goes the same for his team that work with him - definatley our first phone call.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```