# Why is my Javascript not detecting one of my divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am learning how to do a drag and drop activity with javascript.

I would like to check when a div contains another div. I followed this advice from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54019699/how-do-i-check-if-a-div-contains-another-div) but I have a problem.

When I try to check if the third div (id="box3") contains the second one (id="box2"), the alert is not shown. Only if I check if the first div (id="box1") contains the second div(id="box2"), then it is detected.

I write here my code if anyone could help me. Thanks.

```js
class Draggable {

    constructor() {
        this.container = document.querySelector('.box__dragabble');
        this.box = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
        
        this._addEventListener();
    }
 
    _addEventListener() {
        this.box.forEach(element => {
            element.addEventListener('dragenter', this.dragenter);
            element.addEventListener('dragleave', this.dragleave);
            element.addEventListener('dragover', this.dragover);
            element.addEventListener('drop', this.drop);
        });
 
        this.container.addEventListener('dragstart', this.dragstart);
        this.container.addEventListener('dragend', this.dragend);
    }
 
    dragstart(e) {
        this.classList.add('drag_start');
       setTimeout(() => {
          this.classList.add('invisible');
       }, 0);
    }
 
    dragend(e) {
        console.log('dragend');
        this.classList.remove('invisible');
        this.classList.remove('drag_start');
    }
 
    dragenter(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        console.log('dragenter');
         this.classList.add('drag_enter');
    }
 
    dragleave(e) {
        console.log('dragleave');
        this.classList.remove('drag_enter');
    }
 
    dragover(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('dragover');
    }
 
    drop() {
         let container = document.querySelector('.box__dragabble');
         this.classList.remove('drag_enter');
        this.append(container);
        
    }
 
    static init() {
        return new this();
    }
 }
 var boxe = document.getElementById("box3");
  var boxd = document.getElementById("box2");
    if (boxe.contains(boxd)) {
    alert("Congratulations");
}

 document
     .addEventListener('load', Draggable.init());
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 5px solid #000000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box__dragabble {
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  background: #000000;
}

.box__dragabble img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.drag_start {
  opacity: .5;
}

.invisible {
  display: none;
}

.drag_enter {
  border: 5px dashed #112244;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box" id="box1">
      <div class="box__dragabble" id="box2" draggable="true">
        <img src="./img/rose.jpg" alt="rose">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="box3"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: According to your markup, `box3` *does not* contain `box2`, box3 is a sibling to box1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would help us to help you if you added just enough of the relevant code to have the error happen, so we can see exactly what you are doing and where the problem is. Take a look at how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `box3` isn't contained in the `box1`.

Comment: you're already using the console API: stop using `alert` from now on. It's a full thread-blocking call from 20 years ago that no one should be using, or teach using, or be taught to use.

Comment: It is a drag and drop activity, so. when you move box2 from box1 to box3 it is showed like if box3 contains box 2. What I want to do if to open an alert window when you have changed box2 from box1 to  box3.

Comment: I think you meant to do `document
     .addEventListener('load', () => Draggable.init());`, or just `Draggable.init();` given your script is at the end of the `<body>`.

Comment: What I am going to use is a modal window not an alert but I think it would be easy to explain what it is my problem. Thanks @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans.

Comment: Then still: don't use `alert`. Make that line a normal console log, too, with a comment `// this is a modal notice in the real code`. Using `alert` in any JS code, whether it's real code or just "as example" is using ancient JS that should no longer be used, or taught.

Comment: @maswerdna It is showed that I moved the box2 to box3 but I have no return with "congratulations" from the console.

Comment: Your `if (boxe.contains(boxd)) {
    alert("Congratulations");
}` is only called once during the `init()` process. You can add this to the `drop` method to get it called every time a drop happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have moved your alert block into the `drop` method to have it called each time a drop event fires.

```
class Draggable {
    constructor() {
        this.container = document.querySelector('.box__dragabble');
        this.box = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

        this._addEventListener();
    }

    _addEventListener() {
        this.box.forEach(element => {
        element.addEventListener('dragenter', this.dragenter);
        element.addEventListener('dragleave', this.dragleave);
        element.addEventListener('dragover', this.dragover);
        element.addEventListener('drop', this.drop);
    });

        this.container.addEventListener('dragstart', this.dragstart);
        this.container.addEventListener('dragend', this.dragend);
    }

    dragstart(e) {
        this.classList.add('drag_start');
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.classList.add('invisible');
        }, 0);
    }

    dragend(e) {
        console.log('dragend');
        this.classList.remove('invisible');
        this.classList.remove('drag_start');
    }

    dragenter(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log('dragenter');
        this.classList.add('drag_enter');
    }

    dragleave(e) {
        console.log('dragleave');
        this.classList.remove('drag_enter');
    }

    dragover(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('dragover');
    }

    drop() {
        let container = document.querySelector('.box__dragabble');
        this.classList.remove('drag_enter');
        this.append(container);
        //
        // the following block should be placed here to have it called each time a drop event takes place
        var boxe = document.getElementById("box3");
        var boxd = document.getElementById("box2");
        if (boxe.contains(boxd)) {
            alert("Congratulations");

        }

        static init() {
            return new this();
        }
    }
    // this block is called once, during the init() process
    // it should be moved to the drop() method above
    /*var boxe = document.getElementById("box3");
    var boxd = document.getElementById("box2");
    if (boxe.contains(boxd)) {
        alert("Congratulations");
    }*/

    document.addEventListener('load', Draggable.init());


.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100vh;
}

.box {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 5px solid #000000;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.box__dragabble {
    width: 95%;
    height: 95%;
    background: #000000;
}

.box__dragabble img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.drag_start {
    opacity: .5;
}

.invisible {
    display: none;
}

.drag_enter {
    border: 5px dashed #112244;
}


<div class="container">
    <div class="box" id="box1">
        <div class="box__dragabble" id="box2" draggable="true">
            <img src="./img/rose.jpg" alt="rose">
        </div>
   </div>
<div
```

Comment: Thank you very much @maswerdna I extend more this basic activity and it goes perfectly. It has more sense for me your syntax.

Comment: @rgher it's my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

As your "box3" is not contained within your "box2" element, then your condition will fail.

Instead you should use an `else` case that will alert a different message if the case is false.

```
var boxe = document.getElementById("box3");
var boxd = document.getElementById("box2");
if (boxe.contains(boxd)) {
  alert("Congratulations");
} else {
  alert("box 2 is not contained in box 3");
}
```

Comment: It is not detected when I moved box2 to box3 from box1

Comment: it is only detected at the beginning because box2 is in box1

Comment: try this

drop(){
  let container = document.querySelector('.box__dragabble');
  this.classList.remove('drag_enter');
  this.append(container);  
  displayMessageOnDrop();
}

At the very bottom before your last line in the script add another function
(before this line)

document.addEventListener('load', Draggable.init());`

function displayMessageOnDrop(){
  var boxe = document.getElementById("box3");
  var boxd = document.getElementById("box2");
  if (boxe.contains(boxd)) {
    alert("Congratulations");
  }
}